# String search and replace in SystemVerilog

Tags: string, replace, system-verilog

What's the easiest way to do string search and replace in SystemVerilog?

For example, I have:

```
string hdl_path = "DUT.my_red39";
```

How do I create a new `string` that replaces **red** with **blue**?

[EDA Playground link](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/WYx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the SystemVerilog utility libraries that have been created recently.

[**ClueLib**](https://github.com/cluelogic/cluelib)

- has `cl::text::replace` method
- [ClueLib replace example](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Ez)

[**svlib**](http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/)

- has `svlib_pkg::Str::replace` method
- [svlib replace example](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/9KR)

Alternatively, you could do it with plain SystemVerilog by comparing individual characters:

```
  function automatic string search_replace(string original, string old, string replacement);
    // First find the index of the old string
    int start_index = 0;
    int original_index = 0;
    int replace_index = 0;
    bit found = 0;

    while(1) begin
      if (original[original_index] == old[replace_index]) begin
        if (replace_index == 0) begin
          start_index = original_index;
        end
        replace_index++;
        original_index++;
        if (replace_index == old.len()) begin
          found = 1;
          break;
        end
      end else if (replace_index != 0) begin
        replace_index = 0;
        original_index = start_index + 1;
      end else begin
        original_index++;
      end
      if (original_index == original.len()) begin
        // Not found
        break;
      end
    end

    if (!found) return original;

    return {
      original.substr(0, start_index-1),
      replacement,
      original.substr(start_index+old.len(), original.len()-1)
    };

  endfunction
```

[SystemVerilog replace example on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CPs)